# Find and replace string between two delimiters

Tags: sed, replace

How do I replace a string between two delimiters?

Some of the answers I found are close, but I think my need is a little more complex.

I.e. `smb.conf` contains a blank line between shares. I want to target the share I want to update. The first delimiter is "[sharename]" and the end delimiter can be a blank line.

I want to find and replace "writable = yes" with "writable = no" which may be inexactly formatted because of white space, but must occur between my two delimiters.

Comment: Maybe look into [augeas](http://augeas.net/).

Answer (score 1):

Almost there, thanks to this list and  http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2012/12/sed-mutli-line-replacement-between-two.html.

I am able on the command line to replace the "writeable" with "# writeable" and can do so without regard to the Y/N setting, I insert another line later on.

```
sed '/\[${share_name}\]/,/^$/{/\[${share_name}\]/n;/^$/!{s/writeable/\#writeable/g}}' \
< ${input_file} \
> /tmp/parse-smb.tmp
```

While this works on the command line with the "!" escaped "!" it doesn't work in a script file, /bin/sh. I have to remove the escape but then the trigger doesn't hit.

Shell subtleties.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, the "!" was fine, it was the failure of the "share_name" variable to translate. Use double rather than single quotes in this command.

```
sed "/\${share_name}\]/,/^$/{/[${share_name}\]/n;/^$/!s/writeable/\#writeable/g}}" \
< ${input_file} \
> /tmp/parse-smb.tmp
```

Should have realized that the subsequent line also used double quotes.

```
sed -i "s/\[${share_name}\]/\[${share_name}\]\n\thosts allow = 10.50.157.0\/24 \n\twriteable = no/" \
/tmp/parse-smb.tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider perl: untested

```
perl -00 -pe '/^\[your_share_name\]/ and s/writable\s*=\s*\Kyes/no/si' smb.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a job for perl (or python if you're so inclined.)

```
iMac$ cat ./replace.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

while (<>) {
    if (/^\n/) { $replace = 0; }
    if (/\[share3\]/) { $replace = 1; }
    print unless /writable/;
    if (/writable/) {
    if ($replace == 1) {
        print "  writable = no\n";
    }
    else {
        print;
    }
    }
}
iMac$ cat smb.conf 
[share1]
  writable = yes
  user = anonymous
  host = remote

[share2]
  writable = yes
  user = anonymous
  host = remote

[share3]
  writable = yes
  user = anonymous
  host = remote

[share4]
  writable = yes
  user = anonymous
  host = remote

[share5]
  writable = yes
  user = anonymous
  host = remote
iMac$ cat smb.conf | ./replace.pl
[share1]
  writable = yes
  user = anonymous
  host = remote

[share2]
  writable = yes
  user = anonymous
  host = remote

[share3]
  writable = no
  user = anonymous
  host = remote

[share4]
  writable = yes
  user = anonymous
  host = remote

[share5]
  writable = yes
  user = anonymous
  host = remote
```